# Request to delete [apoc]

Tags: support, tags

I just posted a new question and accidentally created the apoc tag, when I wanted to use the neo4j-apoc tag. It does not look like I have the ability to delete the tag, so I would appreciate if someone could fix my mistake.

My apologies. I will be more careful from now on.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Since there are no questions tagged with it, it'll get cleaned up automatically. Didn't you get a warning when you created a non-existent tag?

Comment: Yes, I saw the warning. It registered in my head after I clicked to proceed anyway that there was probably a tag already in existence.

Comment: Ah, I see. In general, assume that the appropriate tag already exists, and look for alternate spellings. Anyway, I think the suggested target addresses your question. If so, you can accept the duplicate closure.

Comment: The tag autocompletion in questions is not always the best. If you're not sure if a tag exists, [the tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) has a more useful search.